# Rails remember me function just keep remembering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My remember feature if simply login will still create a permanent cookie. I followed the following tutorial :http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

Here what I have

Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if current_customer
        redirect_to current_customer
    end
  end
  def create
    customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:email])
        if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:password])
        if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = customer.auth_token
        else
        cookies[:auth_token] = customer.auth_token
        end
            redirect_to customer, :notice => "Logged in!"
        else
            flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
            render "new"
        end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  force_ssl

  private

    def authorize
        redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_customer.nil?
    end

    def current_customer
      @current_customer ||= Customer.find_by_auth_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end
    helper_method :current_customer
end
```

I was thinking of adding a delete if params wasn't check off to assure myself no other cookie existed. But that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should call the helper_method call at the top of your class.

Comment: I have place helper_method :current_customer on top of class but still the cookies seem to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  reset_session
```

to your destroy action.